# Erro ao utilizar o iFrame

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iframe

Possuo uma aplicação desenvolvida em  `Asp.NET MVC-5`  e publicada no IIS normalmente. Ao acessar a aplicação pelo link a mesma funciona corretamente, todos os links.

Porém, necessito colocar esta página dentro de um `iframe` no site oficial.
Ao colocar o link no   `iframe` eu acesso a aplicação normalmente, porém UM método não funciona, somente este. Ao clicar nele, nada acontece. Verificando no console do  `Chrome`  eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> Refused to display 'Link aqui' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

O restante de minha aplicação funciona normalmente, porém somente este método me retorna este erro.

A página que o link está chamando possui este código:

```
@using PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities
@model PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities.Usuario


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    @{
        Layout = null;
        ViewBag.Title = "Dados Cadastrais";
    }
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquerymask")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.editable.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/select2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/select2/css/select2-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/select2/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/prettify.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cidades-estados-js.googlecode.com/files/cidades-estados-v0.2.js"></script>
    <title>CETIL - Atendimento ao Servidor</title>
    <link href="~/Content/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Inicial.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <style type="text/css">
        .imageA {
            position: absolute;
            left: 500px;
            top: 0px;
        }

        .mapLocal {
            position: absolute;
            left: 115px;
            top: 60px;
            font-size:13px;
            font-family: Verdana;
        }

        .Nome {
            position: absolute;
            left: 860px;
            top: 220px;
        }

        .faq-cat-tabs li a {
            padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            color: #777777;
        }
    </style>

</head>



<body>
    <a><img src="~/Content/img/img_top.png" width="361" height="54" class="imageA"></a>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    @Html.Partial("_MenuCompleto")
    <div class="Nome">
        <p><strong><font face="Arial" size="2"> @ViewBag.Matricula / @ViewBag.Contrato - @ViewBag.Nome</font></strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="mapLocal">
        <img src="~/Content/img/sitemap.ico" width="19" height="19" /> Você está em: <i>@ViewBag.Title</i>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>
            <div id="message">
                      @{
                          if (TempData["MensagemError"] != null)
                          {
                              <div>
                                  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                      <span class="sr-only">Error: </span>@TempData["MensagemError"]
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          }


                          if (TempData["Mensagem"] != null)
                          {
                              <div>
                                  <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                      <span class="sr-only">Error: </span>@TempData["Mensagem"]
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          }


                          if (TempData["MensagemCPF"] != null)
                          {
                            <div>
                                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Error: </span>@TempData["MensagemCPF"]
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          }
                          if (TempData["MensagemPIS"] != null)
                          {
                            <div>
                                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Error: </span>@TempData["MensagemPIS"]
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          }

}
                  </div>

        </p>
    </div>

    <!--ABAS-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills faq-cat-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionE">Pessoal</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionH">Documentos</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionF">Endereço</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionG">Dados Profissionais</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="sectionE" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                    <br /><br />
                    @Html.Partial("_DadosPessoais")
                </div>
                <div id="sectionF" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <br /><br />
                    @Html.Partial("_Endereco")
                </div>
                <div id="sectionG" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <br /><br />
                    @Html.Partial("_DadosProfissionais")
                </div>
                <div id="sectionH" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <br /><br />
                    @Html.Partial("_Documentos")
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




    <div class="container body-content">

        <hr />
        <div align="center">
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Portal RH - <a href="http://www.vilavelha.es.gov.br" target="_blank">Prefeitura Municipal de Vila Velha</a></p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#message').delay(4000).fadeOut();
    });
</script>
```

e estou utilizando o  `iframe`  neste código:

```
<div id="sp-component-area" class="span12"><section id="sp-component-wrapper"><div id="sp-component"><script type="text/javascript">
function iFrameHeight() {
    var h = 0;
    if (!document.all) {
        h = document.getElementById('blockrandom').contentDocument.height;
        document.getElementById('blockrandom').style.height = h + 60 + 'px';
    } else if (document.all) {
        h = document.frames('blockrandom').document.body.scrollHeight;
        document.all.blockrandom.style.height = h + 20 + 'px';
    }
    $response->headers->set('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN', false);
}
</script>
<div class="contentpane">
<iframe     id="blockrandom"
    name="iframe"
    src="SiteAQUI"
    width="100%"
    height="500"
    scrolling="auto"
    frameborder="1"
    class="wrapper">
    Esta opção não irá funcionar corretamente. Infelizmente, seu navegador não suporta frames.</iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguindo o exemplo [deste post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931853/refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameorigin), bastou adicionar este código em meu  `Global.asax`  e consegui abrir normalmente.

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
    {
        Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
         Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "AllowAll");

    }
```