# Duvida sobre X-Frame-Options

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iframe

Ontem tive um problema com o  `X-Frame-Options`, como pode ser visto [neste post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56008/erro-ao-utilizar-o-iframe/56011#56011). Porém, adicionei a solução, e funcionou perfeitamente.
Eu adicionei a solução, porém não tenho ideia do que ela faz, e gostaria de uma explicação.

A solução adicionada em meu  `Global.asax`  foi:

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
{
    Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
     Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "AllowAll");

}
```

Minha dúvida agora é:

O que é  `X-Frame-Options`?

Como se utiliza, e por que causa o tipo de problema demonstrado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`X-Frame-Options` serve para indicar ao browser se e quando seu site pode aparecer dentro de um `<iframe>` de outro site. [A documentação está aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options).

A priori, a configuração é feita no servidor.

Você até pode colocar um comportamento específico para o `X-Frame-Options` (como no caso da sua aplicação), o que está ok, visto que desabilitar esse item do cabeçalho pode fazer com que seu site apareça dentro de outros de forma indesejada.